# In flutter how to get current user logged in from the cache maintained by firebase for signin type of email and password

Tags: dart, flutter

I am able to signin with user in my authentication, but how to get current user aid in dart flutter.

I am trying in this way

```
FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
print(user.uid);
```

but showing error as

> A value of type'()-> Future can't be assigned to a variable of type firebaseuser"

Comment: The error message doesn't seem to be exactly what you get. For example `firebaseuser` with all lowercase. Please always post error messages **exactly** as they are created.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I don't know Flutter well enough yet to be sure, but from your error message, I think this should fix the error

```
    someMethod() async {
      FirebaseUser user = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
      print(user.uid);   
      }
```

Comment: Very helpful and straightforward documentation with examples of `async await` and `future`. https://www.dartlang.org/tutorials/language/futures

Answer (score 6):

Here is a solution that worked for me. I too had the same problem, but I managed to overcome by doing this.
Here is my code snippet

```
String accountStatus = '******';
FirebaseUser mCurrentUser;
FirebaseAuth _auth;

@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  _getCurrentUser();
  print('here outside async');
}

_getCurrentUser () async {
  mCurrentUser = await _auth.currentUser();
  print('Hello ' + mCurrentUser.displayName.toString());
  setState(() {
    mCurrentUser != null ? accountStatus = 'Signed In' : 'Not Signed In';
  });
}
```

In my StatefulWidget class's build method I have a text widget with 'accountStatus' that shows that the user is logged in or not. 
This async _getCurrentUser method get the user from the FirebaseAuth and repaints the account status variable on the screen;
Once you signIn with email and password then the user is easily obtained from the async method. Hope this serves the question
Note that this works even when the internet is off. In that case 'mCurrentUser' is obtained from the Firebase cache.

Answer (score 1):

```js
//dart


String userId = "";

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    widget.auth.getCurrentUser().then((user) { //widget.auth => 'Auth auth = new Auth();' 
      setState(() {
        if (user != null) {
          userId = user?.uid;

          print(userId);
        }
      });
    });
  }
  
  
  //in auth file
  Future<FirebaseUser> getCurrentUser() async {
    FirebaseUser user = await firebaseAuth.currentUser();
    return user;
  }
```

that should help

Answer (score 0):

`FirebaseUser currentUser = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();`
This will simply give you the currentUser already authenticated